# MariaDB docker not starting due to Innodb error

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, innodb

I have a local docker environment (MAC) for my Laravel set-up. The mariadb container in `docker-compose.yml` is defined as

```
    image: mariadb:10.6
    container_name: ct-mariadb
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/storage/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ....
      MYSQL_USER: ....
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ....
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ....
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
```

The set-up used to work fine, but after testing some manual DB changes it corrupted. When (re-)starting the containers via `docker-compose up -d --build` the mariadb container fails to start. In the container logs the following can be found:

```
2022-05-05 23:13:17+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.6.7+maria~focal started.

2022-05-05 23:13:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'

2022-05-05 23:13:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.6.7+maria~focal started.

2022-05-05 23:13:18+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB upgrade not required

2022-05-05 23:13:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.6.7+maria~focal started.

2022-05-05 23:13:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'

2022-05-05 23:13:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.6.7+maria~focal started.

2022-05-05 23:13:19+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB upgrade not required

2022-05-05 23:13:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.6.7+maria~focal started.

2022-05-05 23:13:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'

2022-05-05 23:13:20+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.6.7+maria~focal started.

2022-05-05 23:13:21+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB upgrade not required

2022-05-05 23:13:18 0 [Note] mariadbd (server 10.6.7-MariaDB-1:10.6.7+maria~focal) starting as process 1 ...

2022-05-05 23:13:18 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive

2022-05-05 23:13:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11

2022-05-05 23:13:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1

2022-05-05 23:13:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using ARMv8 crc32 + pmull instructions

2022-05-05 23:13:18 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)

2022-05-05 23:13:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO

2022-05-05 23:13:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 134217728, chunk size = 134217728

2022-05-05 23:13:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool

2022-05-05 23:13:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=507568654,515471506

2022-05-05 23:13:18 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Missing FILE_CREATE, FILE_DELETE or FILE_MODIFY before FILE_CHECKPOINT for tablespace 230

2022-05-05 23:13:18 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Data structure corruption

2022-05-05 23:13:18 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...

2022-05-05 23:13:19 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.

2022-05-05 23:13:19 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.

2022-05-05 23:13:19 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.

2022-05-05 23:13:19 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB

2022-05-05 23:13:19 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I've tried to delete all containers, images and volumes several times via the Docker Desktop UI and with `docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q) docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)` but after starting up the containers I get the exact same error again.

I fail to understand why/how after completely deleting all containers, images and volumes this error can still come back.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: How are you initializing the containers? Your logs are showing from an already initialized version, was the original version 10.6.7 too? It crashed for some reason (hence the crash recovery), is there logs for that? Is a backup occurring at the same time (just asking because of [MDEV-27711](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27711)). As a test you could try the container `quay.io/mariadb-foundation/mariadb-devel:10.6` from 6 hrs ago. A [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org) with some details would be most welcome.

Comment: @danblack I am initialising the containers through ```docker-compose up -d --build``` but have also tried ```docker-compose up```. 
I am not 100% sure about the initial version. I have ```10.6``` defined in my ```yml``` file.
The logs which I could see in docker desktop are included above. Since the container doesn't start-up I can't access it to see if there are other logs.
How can I see if a back-up is occurring? I am not aware that it is.
I tried container image ```quay.io/mariadb-foundation/mariadb-devel:10.6``` but this gives the same result. I'll look into making the bug report.

Comment: I've also tried with image ```mariadb:10.6.4``` and ```mariadb:10.6.5``` but exact same errors as above.

Comment: It sounds like something critical to MySQL was on a mounted volume, and that volume was not mounted, or the files had been changed or deleted.

Comment: @RickJames that could be, but then if I wipe everything and start the dockers from scratch it should work again right? Or could it still refer to some log where I don't know of where it finds a checkpoint to start crash recovery from?? This set-up worked since months and the exact same repo works fine on other machines.

Comment: Well, "think out of the box".  Something is "not "the exact same".

Comment: Thnx @RickJames something indeed wasn't exactly the same. Although I had removed/cleaned all docker volumes a local volume in my project still existed and caused the issue. After I cleaned that everything started working again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 22.04. MariaDB "Starting MariaDB database server mariadbd \[fail\]"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72474571/ubuntu-22-04-mariadb-starting-mariadb-database-server-mariadbd-fail)

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72474571/ubuntu-22-04-mariadb-starting-mariadb-database-server-mariadbd-fail) answer, same log message by the MariaDB InnoDB lead.

Answer (score 1):

For who it might help.....

Although I cleaned the docker containers, images and volumes with the below commands.

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps -a -q)
docker rmi -f $(docker images -q)
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q)
docker system prune
```

My mariadb definition referred to a local volume located in ./docker/storage/mysql

```
  mariadb:
image: mariadb:10.6
container_name: ct-mariadb
restart: unless-stopped
ports:
  - "3306:3306"
volumes:
  - ./docker/storage/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
environment:
  MYSQL_DATABASE: homestead
  MYSQL_USER: homestead
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
  SERVICE_TAGS: dev
  SERVICE_NAME: mysql
networks:
  - laravel
```

After cleaning my project docker >> storage folder (basically getting a fresh pull of my project. I could start the docker again without the above errors.

[image]